# Dell Inspiron 15 3000 hotspot not working

Tags: hot-spot, ap-hotspot

A few days ago I purchased a new Dell Inspiron 15 3567 series, with Ubuntu preloaded on it (did not want to pay Micros@ft's toll);)

WiFi is working, but when a hotspot is initiated to share the wired connection (not really, it is a Huawei modem), the following error is produced:

```
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
```

More info:

Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31)

```
rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

dmesg | grep ath

[   13.220775] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   13.222628] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   13.834171] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:01:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   14.057106] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board id is not exist in otp, ignore it
[   14.237916] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to fetch board data for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0 from bus=pci,vendor=168c,device=0042,subsystem-vendor=1028,subsystem-device=1810/board-2.bin
[   16.100669] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 (0x05020001, 0x003821ff sub 1028:1810) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 1 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[   16.100673] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   16.102088] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[   16.102090] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   16.102092] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   16.102092] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[   16.501364] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[   30.732272] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[   30.835092] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[   39.850179] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x82f4
[   39.850181] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   39.850183] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   39.850184] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[   39.850184] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CH
[   39.850185] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[   39.850186] ath: regdomain 0x82f4 dynamically updated by country IE
[   54.550999] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!

lspci | grep -i ether

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

I checked and the firmware seems to be loading correctly.
*UPDATE
The firmware seems to be the problem. Do not know how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

*UPDATE

After doing a:

```
sudo iw reg set IS (<---country code)
```

The output is:

```
Regulatory domain changed to country: CH

[ 7538.843934] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
[ 7538.843936] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), 
(max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 7538.843940] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 7538.843943] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 7538.843947] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 7538.843950] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
[ 7538.843953] cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 7595.819122] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[ 7595.821263] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
```

Not the solution

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a wireless network that other computers can connect to, you need a minimum of 2 wireless adapters, you can get another one by buying a usb dongle, they are usually pretty cheap, around 7 dollars. Once that's done you can follow this tutorial:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Ian for your answer. I have finally found the problem. I was mistaken thinking the Realtek adapter had something to do with my hotspot not working. The problem comes from the Qualcomm adapter. The firmware is not loading correctly. So I downloaded a **live debian buster non-free iso** and burn it to a USB. **Buster** comes with the 2017 firmware for Qualcomm. I tested it and hotspot works perfectly. Nevertheless, I need to update this firmware to my **Ubuntu** dist. I downloaded and updated to firmware-atheros-20170823-1?_all.deb, but gets dependencies issues and a broken package.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Yes, figured it out, but not yet solve it. Cannot update the **Qualcomm's firmware** to the latest on my **Ubuntu**. Any ideas how I can do this?